# How to delete specific record in firebase having specified Title

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was using Firebase Database in Web App, and have data like this yet:

[image: Show Image]

How can i delete the entire record having "Apple" in title (marked in picture)?

I wrote the below code but it's not working.

Kindly Help.

```
var abc = firebase.database().ref('firebase-test');
var key_to_delete = 'Apple';
var query = abc.orderByChild('KISNx87aYigsH3ILp0D').equalTo(key_to_delete);
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot)
{
    snapshot.ref.remove();
});
```

It's not giving me any error in Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're ordering/filtering on the wrong property. You have the value of he `title` property, so should order on that:

```
var abc = firebase.database().ref('firebase-test');
var key_to_delete = 'Apple';
var query = abc.orderByChild('title').equalTo(key_to_delete);
query.on('child_added', function(snapshot)
{
    snapshot.ref.remove();
});
```

Alternative, since you know the key of the item you want to delete, you can also delete that item without a query:

```
var abc = firebase.database().ref('firebase-test');
abc.child("KISNx87aYigsH3ILp0D").remove();
```

Comment: & Sir what about if i only want to delete child node ? not the entire record ?

Comment: `abc.child("KISNx87aYigsH3ILp0D/title").remove();`